# where are the records "for record in event['Records']:" in the lambda handler for loop from?

Tags: amazon-web-services, for-loop, parsing, aws-lambda

A naive question, does anyone know where are the Records in the for loop from? I understand the parsing is happening below but not sure where is the Records dict from

```py
def handler(event, context):
  for record in event['Records']:
    bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = record['s3']['object']['key']
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html) an S3 event (the event variable passed to your handler) looks something like:

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "eventVersion": "2.1",
      "eventSource": "aws:s3",
      "awsRegion": "us-east-2",
      "eventTime": "2019-09-03T19:37:27.192Z",
      "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
      "userIdentity": {
        "principalId": "AWS:AIDAINPONIXQXHT3IKHL2"
      },
      "requestParameters": {
        "sourceIPAddress": "205.255.255.255"
      },
      "responseElements": {
        "x-amz-request-id": "D82B88E5F771F645",
        "x-amz-id-2": "vlR7PnpV2Ce81l0PRw6jlUpck7Jo5ZsQjryTjKlc5aLWGVHPZLj5NeC6qMa0emYBDXOo6QBU0Wo="
      },
      "s3": {
        "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0",
        "configurationId": "828aa6fc-f7b5-4305-8584-487c791949c1",
        "bucket": {
          "name": "lambda-artifacts-deafc19498e3f2df",
          "ownerIdentity": {
            "principalId": "A3I5XTEXAMAI3E"
          },
          "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::lambda-artifacts-deafc19498e3f2df"
        },
        "object": {
          "key": "b21b84d653bb07b05b1e6b33684dc11b",
          "size": 1305107,
          "eTag": "b21b84d653bb07b05b1e6b33684dc11b",
          "sequencer": "0C0F6F405D6ED209E1"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

So you're looping through all of the `Record` entries that are in the array.  While S3 tends to only have a single record, you should parse them all just in case.